# Is there a way to have a Spring @Async method defer execution until a condition is true?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have tasks called using an @Async method that should only be run when a given condition is true. If the condition is not true the task should be kept to be run later. Essentially I am looking to do the following:

```
@Async
public void doTask() {
  if (checkCondition()) {
      // task logic
  }
  else {
    // put this task in back of queue
  }
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish something to this effect?

Comment: when is the `checkCondition` known? compile or runtime?

Comment: At runtime; it depends on calling an external API.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any messaging queue and use the consumer whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use CompletableFuture that resolves when condition is true